# How to reinstate window buttons in GNOME software and GNOME calendar in Ubuntu Unity?

Tags: unity, titlebar, window-decoration, 22.10

I am running Ubuntu Unity 22.10. For some reason, GNOME Software (the one installed with apt, not the snap store) and GNOME Calendar do not have a titlebar, and do not have any window buttons. It might be due to gtk3-nocsd.

How to make GNOME Software or GNOME Calendar show window buttons?

If it is really due to gtk3-nocsd, is there any way to selectively deactivate gtk3-nocsd for GTK4 or libadwaita apps like GNOME software?

[image]
The screenshot shows that GNOME calendar does not have a titlebar (hence, close/minimize/maximize buttons), whereas the file manager Nemo works fine.

Comment: What do you mean with "no titlebar"? No legacy title bar? No top bar with client side decorations? In case of the former, it is expected gtk3-nocsd *adds* such titlebar. That, however, may not anymore work with some applications, and quite likely will not work with gtk4 applications.

Comment: @vanadium See the attached screenshot in the edited question. I really don't need a titlebar. All I need is proper window buttons.

Comment: OK, this is more clear: you are now missing window control buttons. It appears that gtk3-nocsd actually cannot draw a legacy titlebar around some CSD applications, even GTK3 ones (such as Calendar in Ubuntu 22.04).